# What does "twice" mean in " Once bitten, twice shy"?

Tags: word-meaning

There is a proverb saying "Once bitten, twice shy", and I am not sure what "twice" means here.

Does it mean

> Once you are bitten, you get twice as shy as before

or

> Once you are bitten, you get shy the next time

Also, does "once" means the same as the one in this sentence?

Is "once" in "Once bitten, twice shy" a conjunction or an adverb?

Comment: It says "twice", i.e., two times, but the exact number isn't important.  The meaning is that it takes a long time to reestablish trust or confidence once it's shaken.

Comment: *"On the first occasion, if you are bitten, on the second occasion you will be significantly more cautious"* doesn't scan as well

Comment: It's similar to the use of "twice" in another phrase, "Fool me once, shame on you. Fool me **twice**, shame on me."

Comment: @tkp I disagree. In your example your _once_ and _twice_ refer both to being fooled. But in op's example the first _once_ refers to being bitten, but the _twice_ refers to something else

Comment: Does it help to turn it around, and add some extra words?  Someone who gets **bitten once** is likely to react by **shying twice**.

Comment: Another well-known example of this usage is in the Lionel Richie song "*Once, Twice, Three Times a Lady*".  The woman in question is obviously still just *one* lady.  But I guess she's just - *more* of one?  It's poetic exaggeration.

Comment: I always took it to mean that if you were bit on one occasion, you would be extra-careful not only on the following similar occasion, but on the occasion after the following occasion as well.

Comment: This makes me want to start listening to Christmas music!  (This is an emphasized lyric in a common song.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman -> "She's a [great lady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Times_a_Lady#Background), she's a great mother, and she's a great friend."

Comment: It can be confusing because *twice* can mean two different things, it can be a count of frequencies (I go to the gym twice a week), or it can be synonymous with "double" (he's twice bigger). In this case, the correct meaning is the second one. So it can be interpreted as "one time bitten, you'll be double shy"

Comment: @tkp "Twice" is used completely normally in your example. You are internally shamed if you get fooled two times by the same person. In "Once bitten, twice shy" there's a very good question about "twice". So good I don't know the answer.

Comment: As a general point proverbs can be the last resting place of archaisms, and can also have been abbreviated across the ages to the point that the original grammar is obscured. This might be one example -- I don't know. (A well known proverbial archaism: "hoist by his own petard". If you look it up as I once did, a petard is an ancient sort of siege-cannon, that was somewhat prone to exploding and blowing its unfortunate gunner into the air.)

Comment: @ nigel222, you're right of course. The crux of the OP's question *Just Is* that it's not immediately obvious whether "twice" refers to magnitude or number, and my example simply doesn't have that ambiguity. Dunno what I was thinking! +1

Comment: +1, too, for your excellent petard comment. A related effect is where historically literal phrases have been mangled into nonsensical modern idioms. I particularly like how  *"hold the fort"* has morphed, particularly in the US, into *"hold **down** the fort"*. An image comes to mind of some US cavalrymen, struggling with ropes to prevent a huge, inflatable, fort-shaped kids' bouncy castle (US: bounce house) blowing away in the wind.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman great example!  We're expected to understand that she has three units of ladiness, whatever those are, not six.  In the song, as in the idiom, the times are not cumulative; being shy once after being bitten once is enough to be "twice shy".

Answer (score 26):

The literal meaning of the proverb is that after being bitten on one occasion a person will be shy on two occasions. The Free Dictionary gives multiple meanings, including "Once one is hurt by someone or something, one will be extra cautious to avoid that person or thing." "Twice shy" suggests that the extra caution **continues** to be exercised.

The grammar of the proverb is ambiguous due to its brevity. "Once" can be understood to mean "on a single occasion", but it could also be understood to mean "After being". This second understanding would be emphasised in a paraphrase "Once bitten *you will be* twice shy". I believe the first meaning is more likely because of the parallel structure where "once bitten" is matched with "twice shy".

Other interpretations of the proverb suggest that "twice" refers to being doubly cautious in the future. This would be clearer in the paraphrase "Once bitten, twice *as* shy". To me the word "shy" already indicates caution, and possibly excessive caution, so this interpretation is also less likely.

Comment: "Twice as shy" is not a paraphrase though, because this is not the meaning of "shy" in the proverb.  "Shy" here is a verb, not an adjective.

Comment: @Graham Why do you think "shy" is a verb here? "Shy" parallels with "bitten", which is either the past participle from a passive construction, or an adjective. It has no tense, either, so I don't see how "shy" can be a verb".

Comment: @gotube I think it’s a valid reading. As a verb shy means to start away in fright. If you have been bitten once, you may well shy twice.

Comment: @gotube Yes, "bitten" is a passive-tense past participle.  As for a tense for "shy", proverbs naturally drop words for brevity, which in English tends to make them look like imperative forms.  These are not commands but are statements of something which is predicted to happen.  For example "mess with the bull, get the horns".  There's probably an official name for that grammatical mood/structure, if we went digging for it, but I hope you get my meaning. :)

Comment: While I like your comment on ambiguity, it makes me think that perhaps the use of *once* should be regarded as more of a pun than an ambiguity.

Comment: Now I think about it, in practice I have always interpreted "twice" as referring to *magnitude*. That is, I've always interpreted "twice shy" as the "twice **as** shy" that @Peter mentions. In fact,  it never even occurred to me before this discussion that it might be referring to *number* -- i.e. to the result of being "bitten" a second time. The ambiguity over "once" also never occurred to me before, but it doesn't seem to have just as much scope for changing the meaning as much as the ambiguity over "twice" does.

Comment: @HughMeyers, I agree. And in fact there is another reading with shy as a verb. It could be interpreted as a piece of advice, from one person to another, as in, *"If you ever get 'bitten', you should shy away"*. Of course, in practice it simply does *not* mean that; but since we're exploring possibilities...

Comment: "Twice" refers to the thing that makes the person shy eventually.  "If they try to bite you _once_, you get _bitten_; if they try to bite you _twice_, you become _shy_ / _shy_ away."

Comment: I would interpret the phrase as "*If a person does something* once *and gets* bitten, *that person will be less prone to do the same action* twice *because they will be* 'shy'".

Comment: @Simon: I think we had the same thought at about the same time (I just refreshed and saw your comment).

Answer (score 20):

In this context, "twice" means, "the second time you think about doing that same thing". It's a misuse of the word "twice" which normally means "two times", and not "the next/second time".

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/once%20bitten%2C%20twice%20shy) defines the phrase:

> —used to mean that a person who has failed or been hurt when trying to do something is careful or fearful about doing it again

In their definition, "twice" is represented by "doing it again"

Comment: I would argue that it's not a misuse, it's just a colloquial use that's common in idioms. Cp. *fool me once, shame on me; fool me twice, shame on you*. In casual speech you might hear "He does it once, I'll give him a pass; he does it twice, and I'm gonna report him."

Comment: As @GeorgeK. says, the implication is that one bad experience may cause someone to be cautious many times afterwards.

Comment: This is the interpretation I've always made, although I can see the logic of the other answers now.

Comment: It's not a misuse, because it's a count of the number of times.

Comment: @psmears, GeorgeK, Graham: It's a misuse of "twice" because here it doesn't mean the number of times. "Twice shy" literally means being shy two times, whereas in this idiom, it means, "being shy the second time being bit", which means being shy only once, not twice. In both "fool me twice" and "he does it twice", the meaning is "two times", which is correct.

Comment: @gotube twice also means "doubled in intensity" so with that definition, it means "doubly shy" or "shy twice as much" and hence correct

Comment: @gotube I must argue that, strictly speaking, this is not a *misuse*. 'A second time' is a well-attested contextual meaning of the word 'twice;' cp. the well-cited OED sense 1.c for twice, *adv*. (*n*. and *adj*.); the phrase *to think twice* ("to consider a **second** time"); the idiom *an old man is twice a child* ("old age is a **second** childhood"). This use of *twice* is simply not a misuse; it is an unusual but fundamentally standard use of the word.

Comment: @GeorgeK. Ah yes. Then I agree then that "twice" can mean "a second time". I can't say why right now, but the usage of "twice" in those expressions still doesn't feel the same as in this one, so I'm leaving my answer as is. Thanks for the explanations and sharing your research :)

Comment: @gotube: I disagree - it _does_ mean the number of times: that is, being bitten once will result in shyness on not just the next occasion _but on the occasion after that too_ i.e. the effect of one bad experience lasts longer than just till the next time it might occur.

Comment: @psmears So you think the expression means: "Get bitten once, then you'll be shy the next two times"?

Comment: I never really thought about the meaning of the idiom until this question popped up, but somehow I took "twice shy" to refer to an undefined quantity: the victim will experience doubled the fear/distrust when facing the same situation, as in: "His new car cost twice as much as his last one." I see that David Schwartz's answer mirrors my own feeling.

Comment: @gotube: Yes... and (by implication) after that too, just as to "think twice before doing X" means "think a lot about it" rather than "think _precisely_ twice".

Comment: not sure this is correct, I think it's saying "next two times" indicating. I think the phrase is saying (for example) if you are bitten when you are petting a dog, you will not only be cautious of the next dog that you pet, and if it doesn't bite you, when you go to pet the next dog you will still be cautious.

Answer (score 4):

There are two different questions you could ask. One is what the saying means, the other is what the words would mean if they were not a saying. The saying means that a person who has been hurt in the past will be cautious in the future. It does not mean any particular number of times or amount of caution.

The words, were they not a saying, would contrast the singularity of "once" with the duality of "twice". "Once X, twice Y" would say that one must only X a single time to Y more than once. That is, it would mean that a person who had been bitten a single time would be shy on two future occasions.

However, it's important to note that in the saying, it does not mean any particular number of times. It can just mean on a single future occasion. It can mean more than once. It just means a person hurt in the past is cautious in the future.

Comment: Not convinced that "Once X, twice Y" has any definitive meaning. The meaning declared in your answer is but one possible interpretation. "Once" and "twice" don't have fixed meanings in the phrase independent of X and Y. Everything argued in response to the OP's specific phrase could be argued in response to your abstract variant of it. [But perhaps I'm thinking of this differently than you intended.]

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the phrase *once bitten* could be expanded as *once you have been bitten*. It is not referring exclusively to actually being bitten of course but to any unpleasant experience.

The second part *twice shy* could be expanded as *the next time you will be more cautious*. It does not refer, except loosely, to the second time. The assumption is that your caution will continue.

We also have a similar saying *the burnt child fears the fire* (or dreads the fire).

Comment: This is incorrect. "Once" is counting the number of times.

Comment: @Graham yes, exactly.

Comment: @Graham ' "Once" is counting the number of times.' how do you know this to be the case in this instance? It seems highly plausible that it could take on the more general meaning of 'after'.

Comment: @GlenYates Because of the parallel construction with "twice". "Once X, twice Y." contrasts the singularity of "once" with the non-singularity of "twice".

Comment: @Graham I read it as a pun, so it twists 'twice' to mean 'subsequently' but uses the counting meaning to chime with the counting meaning of 'once'. It's like 'time flies like an arrow, fruit flies like a banana' that it is memorable because in breaks the expectation of the meaning of the words set up by the start of the phrase.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Who does "we" represent in this answer?  I've never heard the expression about burnt children, so I'm not part of "we"; who is? :)

Comment: @dannysauer perhaps it is just a UK usage as your profile suggests you are in the US.

Comment: @mdewey - FWIW, in the US there _are_ a number of "some people have to burn their hand on the stove in order to learn it's hot" types of expressions, but I've never heard that specific construction. /shrug

Answer (score 2):

Merriam-Webster [has a definition for this saying:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/once%20bitten,%20twice%20shy)

> a person who has failed or been hurt when trying to do something is careful or fearful about doing it again

This is one of many proverbs that doesn’t make literal sense.  If there’s any explanation for the way it uses “twice,” it has to do with regional slang in England centuries ago.

Another variation is,

> Once bitten, the second time shy.

This has the same meaning.  It’s more standard English, but much less common.

Answer (score 1):

Yes twice shy leans towards the meaning of being *more shy* and knowing not to do it again, not explicity "twice".

And yes "once" here does usually mean someone does it one time, learns his lesson, doesn't do it again.

We use once to mean 'at a time in the past but not now', which fits your context, so it is an adverb.

Comment: "Once" is meaning "someone does it one time", yes.  But in this case it is not meaning "at a time in the past but not now".  It is simply a count of how many times bitten. :)

Answer (score 1):

> once you are bitten by something, you will be twice as shy *of* it

The many meanings of "shy" all connect to avoidance or distancing. One of the meanings of the expression "shy of" is "afraid of" or "staying away from".

There is an embedded pun in the saying, contrasting the multiple senses of "once" and "twice".

Answer (score 0):

#### To understand this, you need to know there is a different meaning of "shy"

"Shy" in this proverb is a verb meaning "to flinch" or "to react negatively to".  We still use the word with horses (and sometimes other animals), to describe their response when they encounter scary situations and panic.  It is not the adjective "shy" meaning "being cautious/fearful".

The meaning of the proverb is that if you are bitten once, you will naturally flinch away from the bite the first time - but the next time you're in a situation where you might be bitten, you'll flinch away *before* you're bitten.  In other words, if you're in a situation where something bad happens to you, in future you'll react as if that bad thing was going to happen again.

In answer to your question about parts of grammar, both "once" and "twice" are adverbs counting a number of events, [which can be called numeral adverbs, iterative numerals, or multiplicative numerals, depending on your grammar reference](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312527/what-is-the-name-for-the-group-of-words-that-includes-once-twice-and-thri#:%7E:text=NUMERAL%20ADVERBS%2C%20which%20answer%20the,of%20Philipp%20Buttmann%2C%20Greek%20Grammar.). "Once" is the count of the number of times you are bitten, and "twice" is the count of the number of times you shy.

Note that this reaction may be a good thing (learning from experience to avoid common hazards) or it may be a negative thing (reacting negatively when there isn't a real need to).  The proverb can actually be used for both these meanings, which is interesting.  Most proverbs have a "moral" meaning of what's good and bad, but this is more describing a situation and not exactly saying that the outcome is good or bad, only that it is what it is.

Comment: The question isn't about the meaning of "shy", it's about the way "twice" is used.

Comment: @Barmar The OP clearly does not understand the meaning of the word "shy" in this context, as proven by their question.  Until you understand this meaning of the word "shy", it is literally impossible to answer how "twice" is used because you are completely unable to parse the sentence.  All other answers fail to cover this.

Comment: @Barmar To answer the OP more explicitly, I've added explanations of the parts of grammar.

Comment: >> "To understand this ..." No you don't.  In the proverb, shy isn't 'to shy (away)', it's 'be/are shy'.  'Once bitten, twice coy' though non-idiomatic, conveys the same meaning.

Comment: @mcalex No it isn't, because that's meaningless.  The proverb does not mean that you *become* shy, which is a continual state of being, it means that you *react* differently to a specific stimulus.  "Bitten" cannot possibly link to *becoming* shy, because this is not a possible consequence of being bitten.  When you know that "shy" here means "shy away", this all has meaning, because it reflects a natural reaction if something tries to bite you and one which is naturally reinforced after actually being bitten.  As for "twice coy", that's doubly meaningless (and is not a proverb that exists).

Comment: @Graham it is possible to be *shy of* something, and that is indeed a likely consequence of being bitten by it.

Answer (score -1):

My insight tells me that the saying has its "punch" in contrasting what the biting party might expect: "that once bitten => once shy".  But the point is to correct his expectation kind of saying "no Siree ... I am not taking it lightly, I am taking it twice as seriously as you would expect. It's not a one-to-one relationship".  (If it was one-to-one the biter could set into motion a circularly-recurring-cyclical-cycle c=2rPI :)

Comment: But there is no "biting party" involved.  The expression is purely about life experiences.